# GradleException Log location

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I need some help finding the Gradle build logs in Android Studio.  I keep running into compatibility issues when adding new Android features to my apps.  My latest one was adding Room db.  My app compiles fine. I add the new dependencies in build.gradle and the app compiles fine again.  As soon as I start trying to use Room I try to build my app it fails. I end up spending hours trying to troubleshoot my build.gradle files to find my errors.  (This has happened a few times)  The Error I got this time is:

> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more
> details.

I can't find where the log is. I am using Android Studio Chipmunk in Fedora 36.  I saw an old posts that showed a buttons and links to the logs.  The posts were older and the users were on Windows and Mac-OS.  I don't seem to have them in the Linux version.  I can't be the only one running into this.  This seems like such a novice issue but I have been looking for a while and can't find the answer.  I don't know how to effectively troubleshoot this if I can't see the detailed errors.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding a screenshot would help a lot (I would not have to install android studio on a linux virtual machine to help you)

Comment: Thanks JustSightseeing.  I appreciate the help.  I don't see how to post a screen shot in Comments but I did not post one because there is just not that much to see.  Just build output and event log.  Nothing in logcat but issues with the VM that don't appear related to my build.gradle issues.  I thought about it last night.  I should have started with the Android Studio documentation after I could not find the solution.  I am going to read it and see what I find.  I will probably learn a few good tricks!  When I figure it out I will post the solution here.

Comment: I needed the screenshot to determine whether you have the options on top ("File, Edit, View....") and what's the layout for the android studio on linux

Answer (score 0):

My build.gradle logs are located in /tmp.
I found them by going to the Help menu then selecting Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data in Android Studio.  This then gave me a popup with an option to Show in Files. The file that appears to contain the data is kotlin-daemon.timestamp.log where time stamp is going to by different for you.[image: Menu option]
[image: Pop up window][image: log file]